# GitHub Actions: name a workflow run triggered manually

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

Using GitHub Actions we have a workflow (`deploy.yaml`) that can be triggered both manually and as a result of a push event:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'env'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options: ...
```

When this workflow is executed due to push event, the run is named as the HEAD commit... but if the workflow is executed manually, the run uses the name of the yaml file (`deploy` in this scenario)

[image: example of multiple workflow runs]

Is it possible to name a run that has been triggered manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This feature is now live from September 26, 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-26-github-actions-dynamic-names-for-workflow-runs/)

Simply specify the `run-name` which accepts expressions:

```yaml
run-name: Deploy to ${{ github.event.inputs.env }} by @${{ github.actor }}

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'env'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options: ...
```

[For further info see the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name)

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

Support for this feature was [added to GitHub Actions on Sep 26, 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-26-github-actions-dynamic-names-for-workflow-runs/)

#### Original answer

As of Sep 3, 2022, it appears that this is not possible. There is [an unanswered feature request discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/11396) on the GitHub Actions community forum, but no apparent decision has yet been made.